# gcloud codebuild sdk, trigger build from cloud function

Tags: build, gcloud

Trying to use the `@google/cloudbuild` client library in a cloud function to trigger a manual build against a project but no luck. My function runs async and does not throw an error.

Function:

```
exports.index = async (req, res) => {
  const json = // json that contains build steps using docker, and project id
 // Creates a client
const cb = new CloudBuildClient();
  try {
    const result = await cb.createBuild({
      projectId: "myproject",
      build: JSON.parse(json)
    })
    return res.status(200).json(result)
  } catch(error) {
    return res.status(400).json(error);
  };
};
```

I am assuming from the documentation that my default service account is implicit and credentials are sources properly, or it would throw an error.

Advice appreciated.

Comment: I assume "no luck" is that no build is run. I suspect you'll always get an operation back but you'll need to check the operation to confirm the failure. See [method](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/cloudbuild/latest/v1.CloudBuildClient.html#createBuild). The code will run as the Cloud Function's service account and this will need permissions to submit|run the Cloud Build job.

Comment: You may want to try running the Cloud Build client code locally and outside the Cloud Function to confirm the behavior. You may want to create a service account to test this and, once you have it working, you'll then know what IAM permissions it will need. Use `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` locally to set the service account.

Comment: Check the Cloud Logging logs too as this should include more details of the failure.